# PHPcs xml config disable some rules

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, phpcs

I understand how phpcs is configurated with xml, but can not find how I disable some sniffs. This ist my current conf (don‘t even know if this is correct):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ruleset name="custom" 
  xmlns="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset/1.0.0 http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://pmd.sf.net/ruleset_xml_schema.xsd">
  <rule ref="rulesets/codesize.xml"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/controversial.xml/Superglobals"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/controversial.xml/CamelCaseParameterName"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/controversial.xml/CamelCaseVariableName"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/design.xml"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/naming.xml/ShortMethodName"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/naming.xml/ConstructorWithNameAsEnclosingClass"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/naming.xml/ConstantNamingConventions"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/naming.xml/BooleanGetMethodName">
    <properties>
      <property name="checkParameterizedMethods" value="true"/>
    </properties>
  </rule>
  <rule ref="rulesets/unusedcode.xml"/>

  <arg name="tab-width" value="2"/>
  <rule ref="Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent">
    <properties>
      <property name="indent" value="2"/>
    </properties>
  </rule>

  <rule ref="Generic.Files.LineLength">
    <properties>
      <property name="lineLimit" value="140"/>
      <property name="absoluteLineLimit" value="0"/>
    </properties>
  </rule>
</ruleset>
```

and I want to disable these:

- `[phpcs] @copyright tag must contain a year and the name of the copyright holder` all doc comment sniffs (I don‘t need them)
- `[phpcs] PHP version not specified`
- `[phpcs] There must be exactly one blank line before the tags in a doc comment`
- `[phpcs] The open comment tag must be the only content on the line`
- `[phpcs] Missing short description in doc comment`
- `[phpcs] The close comment tag must be the only content on the line`
- `[phpcs] Line indented incorrectly; expected at least 4 spaces, found 2` I use two spaces!
- `[phpcs] Missing file doc comment`
- `[phpcs] Line exceeds 85 characters; contains 91 characters` I would like to have a max of 140

and if I want to add more, where can I search the possible configurations?

Comment: Maybe the [Advanced Usage Manual (Limiting Results to Specific Sniffs)](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Advanced-Usage#limiting-results-to-specific-sniffs) can help

Comment: Yeah perfect for command line configuration, but I want to have it stored in my xml

Comment: Maybe the [Annotated ruleset Manual](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-ruleset.xml) can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you all, I found a way: http://edorian.github.io/php-coding-standard-generator/#phpcs

Tried it before and it did not work and found out that I have to click on phpcs (looked selected in the first moment).

Answer (score 9):

An alternative way of ignoring rules is to use the `--exclude` flag.

```
vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=PSR2  --exclude=Generic.Files.LineLength,Generic.WhiteSpace.ScopeIndent app/
```

In order to find the rule name to exclude, find your corresponding ruleset in following directory:

`vendor/squizlabs/php_codesniffer/src/Standards/<coding standard>/ruleset.xml`

The rule name will be in the **ref** node:

```
 <rule ref="Generic.Files.LineLength">
        <properties>
            <property name="lineLimit" value="120"/>
            <property name="absoluteLineLimit" value="0"/>
        </properties>
 </rule>
```

It's quicker & less cumbersome than creating a separate ruleset.

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest finding the most similar ruleset you can, and making a copy which does not include the specified sniffs.

The [Annotated ruleset.xml](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/wiki/Annotated-ruleset.xml) example includes a block that excludes some sniffs from a rule, along with the usage of a custom rule set.

```
 <!--
    Include all sniffs in the Squiz standard except one. Note that
    the name of the sniff being excluded is the code that the sniff
    is given by PHP_CodeSniffer and is based on the file name and
    path of the sniff class. You can display these codes using the
    -s command line argument when checking a file.
 -->
 <rule ref="Squiz">
  <exclude name="Squiz.PHP.CommentedOutCode"/>
 </rule>
```

Most of the work here is to find out how each sniff is being included, which can be found with a GitHub search for the message ([example](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer/search?q=The+open+comment+tag+must+be+the+only+content+on+the+line&unscoped_q=The+open+comment+tag+must+be+the+only+content+on+the+line)) if it's not listed anywhere else.